# Enable UIWebView audio to continue playing after the app enters the background

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uiwebview, avfoundation

**Summary**

The app I am currently developing uses a combination of a `UIWebView`, as well as the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property to play audio. The `webView` content currently plays fine within the `UIWebView` – even playlists go through and play each song without trouble. However, when the app enters the background, the audio stops playing altogether.

From here, I have to pull up Control Centre and continue playing the audio manually. After this has been done, the audio begins to play again without any such problems. It even goes through the playlist without issue.

I have looked into various solutions (including the AVFoundation framework, as well as the AudioToolbox framework), yet nothing seems to work. I am thinking that the audio doesn't continue to play upon exiting because it is getting its audio from an inline video from the `webView`. Saying that, I am led to believe there is a workaround for this if I am able to continue playing the entire playlist by pulling up the Control Centre and tapping the play button.

---

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set WebView Load Configurations
        let webPlayer = URL(string: "https://urlHere.com")
        let webRequest = URLRequest(url: webPlayer!)
        webView.loadRequest(webRequest)
        webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true
        webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
        webView.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
        
        // Set WebView Scrolling Configurations
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        // Set WebView Background
        webView.isOpaque = false
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.10, blue:0.11, alpha:1.0)
        webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.10, blue:0.11, alpha:1.0)
    }
    
    // Hide Status Bar
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    // Disable Zoom for WebView
    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
    
    // Workaround for Scrolling Offset Bug
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.bounds = webView.bounds
    }
    
}
```

**Info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>

<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

---

**Conclusion**

Is there any way to get this to work without the hassle of manually playing the paused song through Control Centre? Even a workaround that would play the music after the background process has paused it? I am just unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I have the same problem,  share with us if you found a solution

Comment: @Ulug'bekRo'zimboyev Currently no solution yet. If you aren't stuck trying to stream embedded content (such as YouTube), I highly recommend switching to an HTML5 audio player. Those seem to work flawlessly with both UIWebView, as well as WKWebView.